# Read/Write android file from windows with python

Tags: android, python, windows, usb, filepath

I'm trying to open a file stored on an android device to *read/write* on it.

The python application is running on my Windows computer, connected via USB to the android device.

But I don't find the way to use a valid file path, like `D:phone/Android/data` to reach my file.

It raise an error :

> No such file or directory

So I wonder how can I reach this file through USB with my python application from Windows ?
Thanks in advance, I hope it's clear enough.

**Edit :**

For example, I tried this code :

```
f = open("Computer\\TotoSmartPhone\\Phone\\Android\\data\\test.txt"),'r')
# then
f = open("Computer/TotoSmartPhone/Phone/Android/data/test.txt"),'r')
```

But, when I use Explorer to reach the *data* repository, and open a command line interpreter to show the path, it uses in fact a temporary directory (*AppData/local/temp...*) to reach this directory. 
Nevertheless, I can't use this path because it's a random one each time the device is connected to PC.

Comment: All usb device using a system driver(how to access it if haven't). Open device with pyusb but is raw! Open a file with true path "D:\\Anroid\\data\\your_file" and write if you have file permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `adb pull` to pull the file from device, and read and write this file. Then, use `adb push` to write the file back to device.